# How can I make this Open Page close in Javascripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to close the window.open() page after set timeout? Please help and use my demo link.

Thanks in advance

```html
<h1>The Window Object</h1>
<h2>The open() Method</h2>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="showNews()">Show News</button>

<script>
  var myWindow;

  function showNews() {
    myWindow = window.open("https://usuallyformal.com/stia6st3zi?key=85fac1f62c65ffe2ea3187662cd8fbc9", "oyanow");
    setTimeout('myWindow.location.replace("https://dikographic.com.ng/", "oyanow")', 5000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      myWindow.self.close();
    }, 7000);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you are opening a window to a page in a different domain you probably are getting an error in the console when you try to access it. Look at the developer tools console and verify that you have an error message.

Comment: Is there away I can close it? Please help not good in JavaScript and jQuery